# I am getting "CucumberOptions cannot be resolved to a type" issue

Tags: selenium, maven, cucumber

I keep getting the above error msg. I have installed java and maven in my computer. Still I have issues.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Mvngrp1</groupId>
    <artifactId>Mvnartftid</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>FirstMavenProject</name>
    <description>myfirstmavenproject</description>
    <properties>
        <projectbuild.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</projectbuild.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>

                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <executable>c:\program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execute</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports/reports</outputDirectory>
                            <inputDirectory>target/cucumber-reports</inputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.10.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: What does the Java file with the problem in it look like? Make sure to include everything, even the import statements.

Comment: And if you are new have a look at https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Comment: And also https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: Also, make sure to use the same version for all `io.cucumber` dependencies to avoid problems